# Customize Firebase-ui auth Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently Firebase open sourced their Firebase-Auth drop in Authentication System on Github. [Firebase-ui auth Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). Although a very good step they haven't released any documentation regarding how can we customize all the UIs present in the package. One option to do so is, clone the full repo and then dig down the code, modify it and then include each and every class, dependency in our Android project. Is there any simpler solution for that?

Comment: FirebaseUI has always been open-source. There is indeed no guide for forking the code and modifying it.

Answer (score 21):

You can create a style in the `styles.xml` resource file and then use that to customize the Firebase-Auth UI. You can set the new style by using the `setTheme()` when creating the Auth instance.

```
startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setProviders(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()
                            )
                    )
                    .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                    .setLogo(R.mipmap.logo)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Here's a sample of how your style theme could be configured.

```
<style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/bg_login</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Using the above method, I was able to achieve this result:
[image]

This still doesn't provide as much flexibility as one would like but you can customize it to some extent so it could work with your brand's logo and color themes.

These are some of the resources you could find helpful if you want to go further with this approach:

https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/auth/README.md#ui_customization
https://gist.github.com/cutiko/9942f76504cbb67c8d04ee6632286dbc
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/229#issuecomment-236868365

Comment: Link only answers are not good answers on SO. Please either edit your question to include the relevant parts from your link that answer the OP's question, or delete your answer altogether (helpful links are fine for comments)

Comment: How did you get your logo to be centred. Mine aligns to the right. Also how do you prevent your main activity from loading before the Firebase AuthUI. In my case, main activity loads faster than Firebase AuthUI. I thought it could be a problem of the background image but then even without it, it is still the same

Answer (score 5):

Create the Following styles in the styles.xml resource file.

1.FULL SCREEN THEME:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_login</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

2.CUSTOM LOGIN THEME.

```
<style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_login</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/youricon</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

3.CUSTOM BACKGROUND IMAGE WITH LOGO.

Go to drawable the right click=>new drawable resource file.
*Name this file **bg_login**, is referenced above*

```
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/cool_photo"/>

<item android:top="120dp">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@mipmap/your_logo"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />
</item>
```

4.CUSTOM EDIT TEXT

```
<style name="FirebaseUI.EditText">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="FirebaseUI.Text.TextInputLayout" parent="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText" />

<style name="FirebaseUI.Text.HintText" parent="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText" />
```

5.CUSTOM TEXT LINK

```
 <style name="FirebaseUI.Text.Link">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlue</item>
</style>
```

Finally when you are creating the Auth instance reference like this:

```
 .setAvailableProviders(Collections.singletonList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder()
                            .build()))
            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.urlogo)
            .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls("https://urls","https://urls")
            .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to customise the authentication screen and changing just the styles won't work for you, you can also use this:

```
AuthMethodPickerLayout customLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
.Builder(R.layout.your_custom_layout_xml)
.setGoogleButtonId(R.id.bar)
.setEmailButtonId(R.id.foo)
// ...
.setTosAndPrivacyPolicyId(R.id.baz)
.build();

startActivityForResult(
AuthUI.getInstance(this).createSignInIntentBuilder()
    // ...
    .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(customLayout)
    .build());
```

This allows you to create a custom layout and you can define the IDs for the different sign in providers that you are using so that Firebase can automatically invoke the correct providers on click of those buttons.

For more information, you can read this: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#custom-layout

Comment: this must be the right answer if it works!!

Comment: Been trying to use this and I have a TextView which I want to be for my Terms of service but somehow the links don't work on the custom page

Comment: Yeah this works.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also add that you can change the labels, hints, error messages, etc. of some input textboxes. This is useful if you want to rename the input field "First & Last Name" to something more private/anonymous like "Display Name"

Simply override the string resource values in each language that your users will use. For example change your `res/values/strings.xml` file to include -

```
<resources>
    <string name="fui_name_hint">Display Name</string>
    <string name="fui_missing_first_and_last_name">Please enter a display name</string>
</resources>
```

You can lookup the relevant field names in the firebase ui repo at [auth/src/main/res/values/strings.xml](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/5b6c9f01f5a674d754d8e9b1242197fe040086e7/auth/src/main/res/values/strings.xml)